# how to convert interface{} to object in golang?

Tags: go

```
type Human struct {
     Name string
}

func (t *Human) GetInfo() {
    fmt.Println(t.Name)
}

func main() {
    var p1 interface{}
    p1 = Human{Name:"John"}
    //p1.GetInfo() 
}
```

now,p1's typs is interface{}, but i want get a Human object.

How to do? i can call p1.GetInfo()

Answer (score 13):

You can use a type assertion to unwrap the value stored in an interface variable.  From your example, `p1.(Human)` would extract a `Human` value from the variable, or panic if the variable held a different type.

But if your aim is to call methods on whatever is held in the interface variable, you probably don't want to use a plain `interface{}` variable.  Instead, declare the methods you want for the interface type.  For instance:

```
type GetInfoer interface {
    GetInfo()
}

func main() {
    var p1 GetInfoer
    p1 = &Human{Name:"John"}
    p1.GetInfo()
}
```

Go will then make sure you only assign a value with a `GetInfo` method to `p1`, and make sure that the method call invokes the method appropriate to the type stored in the variable.  There is no longer a need to use a type assertion, and the code will work with any value implementing the interface.

Answer (score 5):

You can do a type assertion inline:

```
p1.(*Human).GetAll()
```

http://play.golang.org/p/ldtVrPnZ79

Or you can create a new variable to hold a Human type.

Comment: the receiver is pointer,see [http://play.golang.org/p/j6HhHPohBp](http://play.golang.org/p/j6HhHPohBp)

Comment: thanks，I met another case, how do? [http://play.golang.org/p/WHBMTPvEAF](http://play.golang.org/p/WHBMTPvEAF)